# How does a query on documents work when it comes to pricing in Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Let's say that I have a collection in Firestore that stores " Stories " of all users in my app and let's also assume that I have a thousand story saved in there but I want every user when he/she clicks on a certain button retrieves only his/her own stories( not all of them) . I actually did that by using this code in my app

```
db.collection("stories")
        .whereEqualTo("userID", uidOfCurrentUser)
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```

My concern here is : Will Firebase consider this loop as a read for every document? In other words will they charge me for 1000 read every time a user clicks on that button? ( If that's the case it'll be horrific )

Let's say a user have only 2 documents out of these 1000 stories, will they count it as 2 reads or 1000? What's the best solution to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to firestore you will be charged only for data that you receive or change/delete. It doesn't matter how much is on the database.

If you have in your database 1000 stories but your `query` would give you only 2 back you will be only charged for those 2.

You can read more about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing).

[image]

You should also check if your query requires creartiong and index beside the automatic ones. You can read more about that [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing).

Comment: Woow if that's the case then it's really good. But are you sure Tarik? because I'm a little bit new to this Firebase world.

Comment: I am absolutely sure. You will be charged for those 1000 stories only for the storage. But each click of a user to a button (new query) won't increase that costs.

Comment: I have a collection with over 50 000 docs inside where users can search for them with a fulltext search. We never went over the free tier :)

Comment: But when it comes to storage, the free tier gives you one GB per month? So it's automatically renewed every month, is that right?

Comment: What to you mean with renewed?